# I have a script to automatically connect to VPN with AppleScript, how do I make it so it only tries to do it if I'm connected to the internet?

Tags: macos, applescript

Super n00b to the programming world, however I have done the first part. But every time I'm sitting in an airplane or somewhere else where I don't have an internet connection, an error dialog box shows up telling me it's impossible to connect to the VPN.

How can I improve this script to first check for internet connection, then execute the rest, but if there's no connection don't inform me about it, but try again later?

My script for basic VPN connecting:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        tell current location of network preferences
            set myConnection to the service "Private Internet Access"
            if myConnection is not null then
                if current configuration of myConnection is not connected then
                    connect myConnection
                end if
            end if
        end tell
        return 120
    end tell
end idle
```

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple but interesting question. I found this nice solution at [MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=15068):

```
on check_net()
    try
        set the_URL to "http://www.apple.com" as URL
        set dotted_ to dotted decimal form of host of the_URL --> this will return the IP address if there is a live connection 
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end check_net
```

You can call the handler before enabling the VPN:

```
on idle
    if check_net() then
        tell application "System Events"
            tell current location of network preferences
                set myConnection to the service "Private Internet Access"
                if myConnection is not null then
                    if current configuration of myConnection is not connected then
                        connect myConnection
                    end if
                end if
            end tell
        end tell
        return 120
    else
        -- return another value if you want to wait longer if no internet is available
        return 120
    end if
end idle
```

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: You can check two things at a time if you choose your VPN server as URL ;-)